# F# filter a two-dimensional array with multiple arguments

Tags: arrays, list, f#, filtering

I've been stuck for a while with this seemingly basic problem. I have a two dimensional array of strings and another one dimensional array of strings. The one dimensional array consists of some of the elements present in one of the columns of the two dimensional array. The result that I wish to get is a two dimensional array which is filtered by the elements in the two-dimensional array. As an example:

two-dimensional array:

> [["A", "elephant"], ["B", "dog"] , ["C", "cat"] , ["D", "mouse"], ["E", "giraffe"]]

one-dimensional array:

> ["elephant" , "cat" , "giraffe"]

desired result:

> [["A", "elephant] , ["C", "cat"] , ["E", "giraffe"]]

I thank you in advance for your help. I'm pretty new to F# and trying to learn it has been difficult until now.

cheers

Comment: and your `,` are intendet to be `;`s right? If not you got lot's of one-element lists with tuples in them ...

Comment: These aren't arrays; they're lists. And your two dimensional array is a list of lists.

Comment: Using commas instead of semicolons is one of typical beginner's mistakes, I guess most of us hit it as some point. Do you actually have nested arrays there for some reason, or are you free to represent that data however you wish? Having nested arrays isn't a first choice in F#, you'd really want it to be a list of tuples.

Comment: Daniel: well, it actually would be a list with a single tuple inside, wouldn't it - I understand we may consider this to be pseudocode.

Comment: I actually don't have any restriction on whether to use tuples, arrays, list, etc. Just wrote it that way for making my question clear. I am now trying my way through Seq.map but haven't been succesful so far. Thank you all for your responses!

Comment: @scrwtp i forgot to tag you

Comment: @CarstenKönig if I did use [(string*string)] how could I use a lookup method? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what you actually want to do, but it sounds like finding the right representation is the most important part of the question. In your example, your nested lists always contain just two values (e.g. "A" and "elephant") and so it would make more sense to use a list of tuples:

```
let things = [ ("A", "elephant"); ("B", "dog"); ("C", "cat");
               ("D", "mouse"); ("E", "giraffe")]
```

This representation will make things easier, because we only need to check if the second element of the tuple is in the list used for filtering:

```
let filter = ["elephant" ; "cat" ; "giraffe"]
```

To do that, you can use `List.filter` to filter a list. In the condition, you can get the animal using `snd` (get second element of a tuple) and then use `List.exist` to see if it is in the list of animals to be included:

```
things |> List.filter (fun nested ->
  let animal = snd nested
  filter |> List.exists (fun a -> a = animal))
```

If you want to make the lookup more efficient, you can create a set of filtered items:

```
let filter = set ["elephant" ; "cat" ; "giraffe"]
things |> Seq.filter (fun nested -> filter.Contains(snd nested))
```

And, in fact, you can use function composition to call `snd` followed by the check:

```
things |> Seq.filter (snd >> filter.Contains)
```

This means exactly the same thing as the line above - it takes the tuple with the letter and animal name, extracts the animal name using the `snd` function and then passes the name to `filter.Contains` to see if it is in the set.

Comment: Also worked and very efficiently! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a list of tuples like this one:

```
let animalList = 
    [("A", "elephant"); ("B", "dog"); ("C", "cat"); ("D", "mouse"); ("E", "giraffe")]
```

And another list of animals you want to keep, let's make it a set while we're at it:

```
let animalsToKeep = 
    ["elephant"; "cat"; "giraffe"] |> Set.ofList
```

Then define a function that filters a list of tuples, keeping only those that appear in a given set

```
let filterWithSet set lst =
    lst 
    |> List.filter (fun (_, elem) -> Set.contains elem set)
```

And call it:

```
filterWithSet animalsToKeep animalList
```